# Switch git branches in staging server

Tags: git, github, deployment

In workplace, we are using two servers:

1. **Production:** which is the main server and we deploy from master branch.
2. **Staging:** Which is used to test the new features of the website.

Each new feature is in their own branch. For example, `staging`, `feature-forum`, `feature-chat` etc. Usually `staging server` use the `staging` branch for deployment. However, when a new feature is ready for testing we want to push the new feature to staging server. Is there any way to change the git branch in `staging server` without any merge conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do forced push, e.g. `git push -f staging feature-forum:staging`.